# Как изменить код в рантайме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

Есть у меня такой код:

```py
def myfunction(a, b):
    return a*b*a*b

exec(input())

print(myfunction(10, 5))
```

Что мне передать функции `exec()` чтобы `myfunction(a, b)` всегда возвращал 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Это, например

```
myfunction = lambda *a:1
```

Comment: можно ли каким-то другим способом изменять код функции?

Comment: Можно, но заменить её на другую всегда проще. Манки патчинг.